# how to get the fontsize and fontname of a UINavigationBar in swift?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have my navigationbar, which I did not set the font and leave all default.
From what I researched it must be in `navigationBar.titleTextAttributes`, but I don't know how to get the fontattributes from titleTextAttributes.

How can I get the fontsize and fontname of my navigation bar ?

```
var navigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 40));
navigationItem.title = "my Title";
let fontsize=navigationBar.titleTextAttributes.????????
```

**Update: What am I trying to do?**

I am calling a ViewController in modal mode (popover) to show a smaller dialog. This dialog has a navigation bar. When creating the navigationbar by code:

```
        var navigationBar = UINavigationBar();
        let navigationItem = UINavigationItem()
        navigationItem.title = sBookmarktitle;
        // Create left and right button for navigation item
        let leftButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: sBacklabel, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "backAction:")
        let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: saddBookmark, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "addBookmarkAction:")

        // Create two buttons for the navigation item
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton
        navigationBar.items = [navigationItem];
        self.view.addSubview(navigationBar);
```

and calling the ViewController like this:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Bookmarks") as! BookmarkViewController;// UIViewController
vc.parentviewname=callerName;

vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
let popoverPresentationController = vc.popoverPresentationController
// result is an optional (but should not be nil if modalPresentationStyle is popover)
if let _popoverPresentationController = popoverPresentationController {

    // set the view from which to pop up
    _popoverPresentationController.sourceView = actualViewController.view;
    _popoverPresentationController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection.allZeros;
    actualViewController.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Then it looks like this :

[image]

As you can see the navigationbar looks not very good :-). So I tried to set the size manually :

```
navigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, fDialogWidth, navbarHeigth))
```

I try to calculate the minimal width of my navigation bar. My approach would be to calculate all sizes of text I have in my bar with some spaces between:
Title + left link ('back') + right link('add'). 
For this I need the fontsize and fonttype.

Probably this approach is not best practice ?

Answer (score 0):

Do not add the navigation bar as a subview to your view controller. Do exactly the opposite: add the view controller as a sub-view-controller to a navigation controller that has a navigation bar! Like this:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc2 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Bookmarks") as! BookmarkViewController;// UIViewController
vc2.parentviewname=callerName
let vc = UINavigationController(rootViewController:vc2)
```

Now your view controller (BookmarkViewController) configures its own `navigationItem` as usual.